# Finding and replacing from a large file

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

Masking problem: I need to locate and mask (i.e., replace with say "XXX") certain terms (words/expressions) from a single, large text file (input.txt, 100+ MB). The terms (10K+) that I need to locate are saved in a single file (to_mask.txt). How can I perform this in an efficient way?

I was thinking of doing this in two steps: first locate the rows that actually contain the terms

```
grep -Ff to_mask.txt -o -n input.txt
```

Next go through the output and do the actual replacing (term -> "XXX").

This seems a bit tedious, can it be done in a smarter way?

Any combination of basic commands (grep, sed, awk, one-line-perl) are welcome!

**UPDATE:**

MarcoS, Kenavoz, Ed Morton and Sobrique all gave working solutions, thanks!
I chose Sobrique's solution as my accepted solution, since it was much faster than the rest given my data. It may not handle some special cases, but I'm sure it can be extended to able to do so, plus it does the job at hand in its current condition.

**UPDATE2:**

For reference, here's the solution provided by Kenavoz:

```
sed -f <(sed 's~^~s\~~;s~$~\~XXX\~~' to_mask.txt) input.txt
```

Comment: I think you first should familiarize yourself with concept of the [Scunthorpe Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), and then approach this problem with more than a one liner (especially if other end users are involved). Also filtering of masks are often circumnavigated with 0 b 5 C u r 1 + y, that computers find hard to spot, whilst humans tend to be able to read.

Comment: Thank @Draw Sloan, I am somewhat familiar of the spamming problem. However, I need to implement this with as few libraries as possible (it will be run on the client's side) so I can lose a bit from efficiency for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd tackle it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#read the mask file into memory. 
open ( my $mask, '<', "to_mask.txt" ) or die $!;
chomp ( my @terms = <$mask> ); 
close ( $mask );
#build a really big regex
#map quotemeta means handling metachars. 
#if you _know_ there are none, then you can omit this.
#or if you actually want to be able to use regex in your terms file. 
my $mega_regex = join "|", map { quotemeta } @terms; 

   #compile it into a non-capturing regex, and use \b to anchor on word boundaries. 
   #You don't want to be filtering out Scunthorpe ... 
   $mega_regex = qr/\b(?:$mega_regex)\b/;

#<> means iterate 'stdin' or 'files specified on command line'. 
#just like how grep/sed/awk does it
while ( <> ) { 
    s/$mega_regex/XXX/g;
    print;  #to STDOUT
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The non-capturing regex doesn't seem to work, but if I comment it out it works like a charm. By the way, if my mask terms are "a", "b" and "c", is this correct for a non-capturing $mega_regex: (?^:\b(?:a|b|c)\b)

Comment: Hrm, not sure which bit isn't working - but yes, `(?:pattern)` is a noncapturing group. It's not vital in this case, but it's redundant. I'm getting reasonable results (with a much smaller data set) with: `(?^:\b(?:fish|foo|moo)\b)`

Comment: Not sure either, syntax seems to be fine. But as you said, that part is redundant, so your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
while read mask; do sed -i "s/$mask/XXX/g" input.txt; done < to_mask.txt
```

Probably not the most efficient solution in the world, but it should do the job... :-)
As a bonus it just uses the shell and the `sed` command...

**UPDATE**:

This is a solution which is faster (it writes big `input.txt` file just once). 
It first builds a `fullmask` variable, as the concatenation of all masks separated by `|` (the `OR` operator).
Though, I find it less clear than first solution posted... :-)

```
fullmask=""; cat to_mask.txt | while read mask; do fullmask="$fullmask|$mask"; done && sed -i "s/$fullmask/XXX/g" input.txt
```

Please not I have not tested this solution, it could contain some issue...
More, it assumes `to_mask.txt` does not contain any `|` nor any `/` characters...

**UPDATE 2**:

Sorry! `sed` does not support regexes, in substitutions... :-(
I came up with this solution using `perl`, much uglier, but definitely working (just tested on a simple use case):

```
 fullmask="("; while read mask; do if [ "$fullmask" != "(" ]; then fullmask="$fullmask|$mask"; else fullmask="$fullmask$mask"; fi; done < to_mask.txt; fullmask="$fullmask)"; perl -p -i -e "s/$fullmask/XXX/g" input.txt
```

Comment: That will work fine as long as the to_mask.txt file does not contains lines with special characters that would need to be backslashed ... if so then the to_mask.txt could be manipulated prior so that it can be used as above.

Comment: @louigi600: you're right...OP could change delimiters, to avoid `/` problems... But this can be done only knowing the contents of `to_mask.txt` file, and using a character which is not present (if any...).

Comment: @Sobrique: you're right, too... Ughhh... :-) See my updated answer, just posted a write-once solution...

Comment: Thanks @louigi600 for the effort, but as Sobrique points out, the emphasis is on efficiency, then simplicity. I was also thinking about iterating through the masking file, it does perform the job. But since grep already implements the Commentz-Walter algorithm quite efficiently, I didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @MarcoS: delimiters are not an issue, I can control the masking terms, nothing funky will be there

Comment: @MarcoS Thanks, I tested both your answers, but it gives me an error: sed: 1: "input.txt": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: @MarcoS ... no just sed all the special caharacters used in regular expressions ... if none found sed won't replace them. but that would make things even less efficient. Well any solution using a shell is probabbly less then the most efficient. If you want efficiency you're gonna haveto get your hands dirty with some code.

Comment: @vivasra, @ louigi600: right... But see my second update... One liner, working code... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS Thanks, it does do the job. I'll definitely use your code too in the benchmark!

Comment: Those scripts will ALL be immensely slow (even the fastest one) and corrupt the output given various input file contents. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and google UUOC.

Answer (score 1):

You just need 1 command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{t=(t?t"|":"")$0;next} {gsub(t,"XXX")} 1' to_mask.txt input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, also for your comment above!